# Facebook Graph API not showing draft campaign

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In Graph API Explorer I am trying to fetch the list of campaigns for an ad account like so:
`act_#/campaigns`

At the moment the ad account only has draft campaigns and the request above returns an empty array, like so:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to also list the items in draft?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access all draft campaigns with the Facebook marketing API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058289/how-to-access-all-draft-campaigns-with-the-facebook-marketing-api)